# Распарсить текст php

Tags: php, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код php.

```
<select>
<?php
    $i = "(a)(2)(3)(4)(5)";
    $i2 = "(a)(2)(3)(4)(5)";
    $i = str_replace("(", "<option>", $i);
    $i = str_replace(")", "</option>", $i);
    $i2 = str_replace("(", "", $i2);
    $i2 = str_replace(")", "", $i2);
    $i = str_replace("<option>", "<option value='".$i2."'>", $i);
    echo $i;
?>
</select>
```

Вывод кода такой:

```
<select>
    <option value="a1a2a3a4a5">a1</option>
    <option value="a1a2a3a4a5">a2</option>
    <option value="a1a2a3a4a5">a3</option>
    <option value="a1a2a3a4a5">a4</option>
    <option value="a1a2a3a4a5">a5</option>
</select>
```

Как сделать что бы value было таким:

```
<select>
    <option value="a1">a1</option>
    <option value="a2">a2</option>
    <option value="a3">a3</option>
    <option value="a4">a4</option>
    <option value="a5">a5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: <select><?php for ($tr=1; $tr<=5; $tr++){ echo '<option value='"a".$tr'>'"a".$tr'</option>';} ?>
</select>

Comment: @Bloom текст и `value` другое это для примера.

Comment: и я как для примера)

Comment: @Bloom ........

Answer (score 0):

не занимайтесь ерундой с реплейсами. Если у вас входные данные приходят в таком формате, то преобразуйте их к нужному, а потом генерите требуемый хтмл.

```
$keys = explode(')(', trim($i, '()'));
$values = explode(')(', trim($i2, '()'));
$options = array_combine($keys, $values);

foreach($options as $v => $t){
    echo "<option value='a$v'>a$t</option>";
}
```